# Variables from a text file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, text, save, settings

So what I want to do is store data from a text based game I'm making in a file, but I can't figure out how.

After the user sets the variables from the program
(ex: `example1: true
example 2: false
example 3: true`)
And then after the set that, it goes to a settings file.

Answer (score 1):

JSON and YAML are good formats for storing simple data structures (arrays and hashes) in a text file.

As of Ruby 2.0.0, the YAML library is part of the Ruby standard library.

Using the YAML library, you can

- write to your YAML file

  ```
  require 'yaml'
  myData = { :example1 => true, :example2 => false, :example3 => true }
  File.open('stuff.yaml', 'w') {|f| f.write myData.to_yaml }
  ```
- read your YAML file

  ```
  require 'yaml'
  myData = YAML::load_file('stuff.yaml')
  ```

The library also includes a handy [Store class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html) that makes it easier to keep your objects and the text file in sync. You might want to check it out.

Comment: yaml comes with Ruby's standard library--or at least it did.  Does the gem bring something extra?

Comment: [YAML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/index.html) still comes with Ruby's standard library. It's based on [Psych](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html).

Comment: Whoops, I didn't realize that it comes with the standard library. Updating my answer now.